# How to add a methods attribute if its not in __init__

Tags: python, list, class

how can I add an attribute to a method that isnt `__init__` from an outside function .

for example

```
class Year:
    def __init__(self):
        self._list = []
    def add_year(self,year):
        self._year = year
        self._list.append(self._year)
def main():
    year = 1998
    #how do I get this year into the year class to add to list?
```

Comment: You must first create a `Year` object and then call its method `add_year()`.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comment above:

Create an instance:

```
yobj = Year()
```

and pass the value to be assigned

```
year = 1998
yobj.add_year(year)
```

Comment: how do I print out that list once multiple years are added? I am getting errors

Comment: You can either add the print statement in the function within the class OR you can return the list to the main and print it in the main function.

Comment: how would I return a final list to main? because right now I am using my class to create a list. A loop of lines is running and on each loop it calls that class, to add that line line to the list. At the end I need to print the list of all the lines made inside of that class, but I haven't found a way.

Comment: If you are adding multiple years, just print the list from main in my opinion. Returning doesn't make sense in such a situation because it will return everytime you add an year

Comment: How do I call self._list from main once all of the lines are added?

Comment: You just access it as `print(yobj._list)`

Answer (score 0):

The method `__init__` has nothing special except that it is executed when you instantiate an object. This means, you could assign or get an attribute to an *instance* of `Year` pretty much anywhere in your code, not only in `__init__`.

```
class Year:
    def __init__(self):
        # You can define an attribute in __init__
        self.year_list = []

    def add_year(self, year):
        # You can define and access an attribute in any method
        self.last_year_added = year
        self.year_list.append(year)

def main():
    year = 1998

    # You must instantiate a Year first
    my_year = Year()

    # Then execute the method add_year
    my_year.add_year(year)
    my_year.add_year(year + 1)

    print(my_year.year_list)  # [1998, 1999]
    print(my_year.last_year_added) # 1999


    # Note that you can even add attribute outside methods
    my_year.month = 'December'

    print(my_year.month) # December

main()
```

Answer (score -1):

Below is one example see if helps you

```
class Dog:

    # Class Attribute
    species = 'mammal'

    # Initializer / Instance Attributes
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    # instance method
    def description(self):
        return "{} is {} years old".format(self.name, self.age)

    # instance method
    def speak(self, sound):
        return "{} says {}".format(self.name, sound)

# Instantiate the Dog object
mikey = Dog("Mikey", 6)

# call our instance methods
print(mikey.description())
print(mikey.speak("Gruff Gruff"))
```

The output is as below.

```
Mikey is 6 years old
Mikey says Gruff Gruff
```

if you want to learn more about object-oriented way programming in python follow the below tutorial - `[https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/][1]`

Comment: create the object of your Year class y1=Year() then assign the value to your add_year function by y1.add_year("year you want to add"). above code was just an example/sample how to proceed with your query.

Comment: I didn't give to direct answer because I want to you learn from example so in future you won't be stuck again in this situation.